# How to show git branch in Emacs shell

Tags: bash, shell, emacs, git

How can I show the current git branch as part of the Emacs `shell` prompt?

For example, I have this in my `~/.bash_profile` (I'm on Mac OSX 10.9 Terminal):

```
parse_git_branch() {
  git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/(\1)/'
}
export PS1="\[\033[00m\]\u@\h\[\033[01;33m\] \w \[\033[31m\]\$(parse_git_branch)\[\033[00m\]$\[\033[00m\] "
```

which produces a nicely colored bash shell like this:

`name@my-computer ~/code/sample (master)$`

How can I produce something similar in the emacs shell?

Currently when I open `M-x shell` it will open like so:

```
bash: parse_git_branch: command not found
name@my-computer ~/code/sample $
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, after some research found [this](https://github.com/xuchunyang/eshell-git-prompt/blob/master/eshell-git-prompt.el) repo and adopted my code to the following solution:

Get branch name:

```
  (defun git-prompt-branch-name ()
    "Get current git branch name"
    (let ((args '("symbolic-ref" "HEAD" "--short")))
      (with-temp-buffer
        (apply #'process-file "git" nil (list t nil) nil args)
        (unless (bobp)
          (goto-char (point-min))
          (buffer-substring-no-properties (point) (line-end-position))))))
```

Custom prompt function:

```
  (defun 4lex1v:eshell-prompt ()
    (let ((branch-name (git-prompt-branch-name)))
      (concat
       "\n# " (user-login-name) " in " (abbreviate-file-name (eshell/pwd)) "\n"
       (if branch-name (format "git:(%s) >> " branch-name) ">> ")
       )))
```

Configure:

```
  (setq eshell-prompt-function #'4lex1v:eshell-prompt
        eshell-prompt-regexp ".*>>+ ")
```